# Rideshare algorithm to be used for scheduled and adhoc journeys

Tags: algorithms

I need some help writing some pseudo code for a rideshare system for taxi drivers.

The idea behind it is that it would combine real-time incoming taxi journeys and pre-bookings in real-time.

The steps I have come up so far are as follows:

- The system sets a planning horizon of 1 hour (in the picture below its happening between 8am and 9am) and culls all the journey from the system within that time period (pre-bookings, adhoc bookings, etc)
- The system then finds all jobs booked within 5 minutes of each other and groups them together
- The system then determines if the passengers in the cars have agreed to share the journey
- As a vehicle can only take 4 passengers, the system tries distribute the passengers accordingly, i.e. if one vehicle has 2 customers and another has 2 customers, and the above 2 conditions have been met (within 5 minutes of each other, passengers have agreed to share), then the system combines the journeys.

Of course there is the issue of figuring out how close and far each node (pickup or destination) is from each other. I have the lat lon positions for start and destination points but I haven't figured out how am I going to implement this.

The first thing I want to determine is whether my logic is right so far, and i will need your help with this.

Second thing, I want to do is figure out how I would determine whether a pickup is worthwhile. A passenger that lives 10 miles away from another one but meets all of the current conditions would have their journey combined. How do I tackle this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to solve an optimization problem. Realizing this is important for two reasons:

1. You do not necessarily have to find the absolutely best solution (that would take too long to calculate), but you can settle for a good-enough solution. You can fine-tune your algorithm later.
2. You have to very precisely state what you're optimizing for. I assume you want to minimize passenger expenses. However, combining multiple journeys will usually make them longer. Saving a penny is not worth it when my journey takes half an hour longer due to a detour. So there is a secondary optimization to keep the time for each journey reasonably minimal.

If we optimize for time and cost independently, we end up with a large solution space of equally optimal answers. This is undesirably; instead we need to combine cost and time into a single optimization variable. This connection could be something like “*for every 10 minutes of detour, I want to save at least £2*”. It also makes sense to impose additional constraints such as “*Ride sharing may not prolong my journey by more than 20%*” or “*I want to save at least £2 by ride sharing, otherwise don't bother combining my journey*”.

Once we have set up such a system of rules, we could solve the problem simply by brute force – iterate through all sets of journeys with up to 4 passengers, and figure out whether they ought to be combined. This is not a practical approach.

Instead, we need heuristics and filters.

We have to keep the search space as small as possible. Therefore, we can bung out obviously incompatible pairings at once. For example, we can see if the durations of the journeys overlap within that 20% margin. This implies that we not only need the start and end location for each journey, but also the expected travelling time without ride sharing. Filtering for temporal proximity is guaranteed not generate false negatives, provided you use something like this 20% margin.

> #### Example
>
> Let's assume we have 6 rides numbered 1–6. For each ride, we have the columns `id`, `start`, and `duration`. We want to find possibly compatible pairings. With brute force, we would have to look at <sup>n(n-1)</sup>/<sub>2</sub> = 15 pairings (because for any IDs `a` and `b`, the pairing `(a, a)` is not valid, and `(a, b) = (b, a)`).
>
> Our table (sorted by start time) might look like this:
>
> ```python
> ID start duration (start + f*duration)
> 1  08:00 10min     08:12
> 2  08:05 15min     08:23
> 3  08:10  5min     08:16
> 4  08:20  5min     08:26
> 5  08:30  9min     08:41
> 6  08:40  5min     08:46
> ```
>
> For each ride `a`, we can possibly combine it with any later ride `b` where `a.start + f*a.duration > b.start`, where `f` is the maximal ride elongation constraint (in my example: 20% → `f = 1.2`). Applying this criterion gives us the following 5 possible pairings:
>
> ```python
> (1, 2), (1, 3)
> (2, 3), (2, 4)
> (5, 6)
> ```
>
> Python-like pseudocode for this algorithm:
>
> ```python
> rides = rides.sort(by: (r => r.start))
> pairings = []
> for i from 0 to rides.length:
>   max_end = rides[i].start + f * rides[i].duration
>   for j from i to rides.length:
>     if rides[j].start < max_end:
>       pairings.append([i, j])
>     else:
>       break
> ```
>
> This is also a good place to introduce the passenger constraint. Instead of blindly adding a pairing, we only do this if there are enough seats left:
>
> ```python
> seats_per_ride = 4
> ...
> if rides[j].start < max_end:
>   total_passengers = rides[i].passengers + rides[j].passengers
>   if total_passengers <= seats_per_ride:
>     pairings.append([i, j])
> else:
>   break
> ```
>
> This still ignores that we can combine more than two rides. However, this can now be done as a post-processing of the resulting rides. As long as the passenger count is suitable, we can fold `(a, b)` and `(a, c)` into `(a, b, c)`, which should be considered in addition to the existing pairings. Remember also that `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` are equivalent, so it makes sense to view combined rides as sets of rides, not just as tuples or pairs. If we apply these thoughts to the five pairings we already found, we also get
>
> ```python
> (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)
> ```
>
> Finding *all* sharing opportunities becomes fairly easy if we change the above algorithm to work backwards through the rides, as this can reuse existing calculations. This makes heavy use of the ordering to maintain correctness.
>
> ```python
> rides = rides.sort(by: (r => r.start), descending)
> pairings = []
> last_pairings = []
> for i from 0 to rides.length:
>   max_end = rides[i].start + f * rides[i].duration
>   found_pairings = [[i]]
>   for pairing in last_pairings:
>     if pairing[0].start < max_end:
>       new_pairing = [i, *pairing]
>       total_passengers = sum(new_pairing.map(id => rides[id].passengers))
>       if total_passengers <= seats_per_ride:
>         pairings.append(new_pairing)
>         if total_passengers < seats_per_ride:
>           found_pairings.append(new_pairing)
>     else:
>       break
>    last_pairings = found_pairings
> return pairings
> ```

However, it will also be useful to apply possibly inaccurate filters, as we're only interested in a “good enough” solution. For example, we can ignore pairings if they are too far apart, where “too far” is where that inaccurate part comes in. We'd want to defer actual route finding as far as possible, because that really takes time. While we really should be optimizing for time, our heuristics might use the distance on the map. In short, you could draw geometric shapes such as rectangles, circles, or ellipses around each route, and see which ones overlap. That's still pretty crude, and you might get better performance if you store your journeys in a spatial database from the start, and explicitly query for close journeys using such a metric.

After we've applied all filters, we still end up with a couple of candidate ride sharing opportunities. There is no way around calculating possible combined routes. The candidate combined routes are all routes with all start and end points for each passenger as waypoints, with the additional restriction that each end point must come after the corresponding start point. You can then grade each route for each passenger by our optimization metric (and possibly realize that this route would violate our additional constraints).

We have now arrived at the solution space (a set of possible rides for each passenger), and have to pick one solution (which passenger picks which ride). The remaining problem is that one passenger may have multiple options to share rides. When the user picks one option, the passengers of the other options will have to pay more. It is difficult to find the perfect solution where all passengers combined pay as little as possible, so I'd settle for a non-deterministic strategy (at least for now, you can always fine-tune later). The most obvious strategy tries to find the local optimum for each passenger:

```python
for each passenger:
  pick the ride where that passenger has to pay the least fare.
  eliminate all other sharing opportunities that included this passenger.
```

More advanced strategies might use a priority queue of passenger that sorts them by the amount saved, or by an external metric such as booking time.

Comment: Hi @amon - really appreciate your thoughts. I tried resolving this problem yesterday again, and this is the best I could come with: http://pastebin.com/crBNwSzX. What do you think? How can I make it better?

Comment: @methuselah Your updated approach looks OK, except that it ignores different locations – filtering by location would likely greatly reduce the number of possible combinations. Also, it will prefer crammed-full rides over possibly cheaper rides with only two passengers, and will fail to group more than three rides together. All of that is not necessarily a problem (see: good-enough solutions), but those are opportunities for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your fantastic insight, I'll look into this and make it better. I feel really encouraged.

Comment: "We have to keep the search space as small as possible. Therefore, we can bung out obviously incompatible pairings at once. For example, we can see if the durations of the journeys overlap within that 20% margin. This implies that we not only need the start and end location for each journey, but also the expected travelling time without ride sharing. Tip: use an interval tree to group journeys by overlapping time. Filtering for temporal proximity is guaranteed not generate false negatives, provided you use something like this 20% margin." - are you able to give an example of this?

Comment: @methuselah I expanded my answer with an example and a possible algorithm for finding rides with overlapping time.

Comment: Fantastic, this helps a lot!